# All embeded components in Tapestry

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm using Tapestry 5.3.8. I wanted to find a method that will tell me if there is some specific element in given container or not. I have found something like this:

```
containerResources.getEmbeddedComponent(elementId)
```

But problem with this method is that when there is not, it throws exception. I could not see any other method regarding this.

Question: is there any other method to check if some element is inside given container OR is there any method that e.q. list all avaible componenets in given container?

Answer (score 0):

How about [`ComponentResources#getComponentModel()#getEmbeddedComponentIds()`](https://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/model/ComponentModel.html#getEmbeddedComponentIds())?

Comment: It looked very promissing. However, when I try this, I receive an empty list :( (while using  containerResources.getEmbeddedComponent(elementId) returns correct element)

Comment: Ah, it seems it only includes embedded components defined by the `@Component` annotation. I guess the `ComponentModel#getEmbeddedComponentModel(...)` is about the same then.